# Is possible to get the local printers with javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows, printers

I need to get a list of the local printers installed on the machine/computer.
Is it possible?

Comment: Not possible in web applications due to security reasons.

Comment: I understand.. I was trying to know if there was any workaround to this issue. But I was expecting an answer as yours.. anyway... thanks

Comment: Well the "work around" is use standard printing functionality of the browser where the user can select there own printers. If you have full control over the desktops you can install a desktop application that opens an interface to get this data on the machines where you want to get this data.

Comment: I will not use a browser.. I'm including Javascript into a desktop application... It is already a workaround in this case.

Comment: A quick google resulted that nodejs has some options for that.

Comment: As last resort you could use an ActiveX component installed in the client, and then access the local printer list in the activeX object via javascript, but it will only work with Mircosoft browsers.

Comment: It's not possible in my case. but thanks